# How to make an array of all elements following X?

Tags: prolog, predicate

I need to write a predicate `next(X, List1, List2)`, which returns `List2`, an array of elements which directly follow `X`.

For example,

```
next(v1,[v1,v2,v3,v1,v2,v1,v5],L) returns L=[v2,v2,v5]
next(b,[b,k,m,b,j],L) returns L=[k,j]
next(s,[s,b,c,d,e,f,s,c,s,g],L) returns L=[b,c,g]
....
```

I know that recursion and tail must be used.

I think I know the logic and how the predicate should work, but I can't get it to work. Below is how I'd expect the predicate to work if user entered  `next(a,[a,b,c,a,b,c],L).`

```
[a,b,c,a,b,c]
%if first letter is a, put the letter after it in array L, if not - remove first letter.
%first letter is a, put b in array L, remove a from initial array.

[b,c,a,b,c]
%if first letter is a, put the letter after it in array L, if not - remove first letter.
% first letter is b, it is not a, so remove it from initial array

[c,a,b,c]
%if first letter is a, put the letter after it in array L, if not - remove first letter.
% first letter is c, it is not a, so remove it from initial array

[a,b,c]
%if first letter is a, put the letter after it in array L, if not - remove first letter.
% first letter is a, put b in array L, remove a from initial array.

[b,c]
%if first letter is a, put the letter after it in array L, if not - remove first letter.
% first letter is b, it is not a, so remove it from initial array

[c]
%if first letter is a, put the letter after it in array L, if not - remove first letter.
% first letter is c, it is not a, so remove it from initial array
```

**This is what I have:**

```
next(X, List1, List2):-
    next(X,[X,X2|List1],X2).
```

I know the part in square brackets is wrong.

**Update #1:**

```
/* X is the head of the list */
next(X, [X,Y|T1], [Y|T2]) :-
    next(X, [Y|T1], T2).

/* X is not the head of the list*/
next(X, [_|T1], [T2]) :-
    next(X, T1, T2).

/* T1 contains only one element */
    next(X, _, [T2]):-
        true.

/* T1 is empty */
    next(X,[T2]):-
        true.
```

Trace log for Update #1:

1 ?- trace.
true.

```
[trace] 1 ?- next(a,[a,c,d,e,f,a,g],S).
   Call: (6) next(a, [a, c, d, e, f, a, g], _G4792) ? creep
   Call: (7) next(a, [c, d, e, f, a, g], _G4880) ? creep
   Call: (8) next(a, [d, e, f, a, g], _G4885) ? creep
   Call: (9) next(a, [e, f, a, g], _G4888) ? creep
   Call: (10) next(a, [f, a, g], _G4891) ? creep
   Call: (11) next(a, [a, g], _G4894) ? creep
   Call: (12) next(a, [g], _G4898) ? creep
   Call: (13) next(a, [], _G4903) ? creep
   Exit: (13) next(a, [], [_G4906]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) next(a, [g], [[_G4906]]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) next(a, [a, g], [g, [_G4906]]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) next(a, [f, a, g], [[g, [_G4906]]]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) next(a, [e, f, a, g], [[[g, [_G4906]]]]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) next(a, [d, e, f, a, g], [[[[g, [_G4906]]]]]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) next(a, [c, d, e, f, a, g], [[[[[g, [_G4906]]]]]]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) next(a, [a, c, d, e, f, a, g], [c, [[[[g, [_G4906]]]]]]) ? creep
S = [c, [[[[g, [_G4906]]]]]]
```

I have gone through a list of prolog exercises of basic level from these resources:
http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/problemas-prolog/
http://www.anselm.edu/homepage/mmalita/culpro/index.html

Comment: Start with `next(X, [X,Y|T1], [Y|T2]) :- next(X, [Y|T1], T2).` You'll need another clause for when the `X` is not at the head of the second argument, and you will need a base case for when the 2nd argument is empty or only one element.

Comment: @lurker 1.) How can I write a clause for when x is not at the head? I can write a clause for when x,y are the tail. 2.) About base cases, I think I figured those out, but what do I return in them?
Posting my code above.

Comment: @lurker I I am close to being done. Now predicate returns all the right elements, but also some unneeded brackets, you can see that in the trace log I posted.

Comment: Just check `dif(X, Y)` which is true if `X` and `Y` are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've defined what rules you need to solve the problem, but your predicate clauses that define these rules aren't all correct. Let's look at the rules you've defined:

```
/* X is the head of the list */
next(X, [X,Y|T1], [Y|T2]) :-
    next(X, [Y|T1], T2).
```

This is the one I gave in a comment where the head of the list matches the element, and it's correct.

```
/* X is not the head of the list*/
next(X, [_|T1], [T2]) :-
    next(X, T1, T2).
```

This clause has an issue. It says, *X is not the head of the list*, but the query `next(a, [a,b,c], T)` will match it, since `X = _` is possible. Also, and here's where all of your extra brackets came in, `T2` is already a list, so you don't want to put it into brackets like, `[T2]`. The corrected clause is:

```
next(X, [Y|T1], T2) :-
    dif(X, Y),      % Or X \== Y if you don't have dif/2
    next(X, T1, T2).
```

The third rule and clause:

```
/* T1 contains only one element */
    next(X, _, [T2]):-
        true.
```

This has an issue because `_` matches *anything*, not just single element lists. The rule says, *`T1` contains only one element*. But `T1` doesn't even appear in the clause. The corrected version would be:

```
/* A list with one element has no elements "next" */
next(_, [_], []).
```

So in the above, it no longer matters what the first argument is, and the 2nd argument is any list of one element, no matter what it is. The result must be empty.

And your last rule & clause:

```
/* T1 is empty */
    next(X,[T2]):-
        true.
```

One glaring issue is that you now just have 2 arguments. Your predicate must have 3. And if `T1` is empty, I would expect the middle argument to be `[]`:

```
/* An empty list has no "next" values */
next(_, [], []).
```

You could also combine the last two clauses as:

```
next(_, T, []) :- T = [] ; T = [_].
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and detailed comments and answer!